# A film with three astronauts with one I believe is deceased but a pen is put into his hand and he scribbles something on paper

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

I remember a film where one of the astronauts is apparently dead but the other two put a pen in his hand and he scribbles something on paper. Also, where they try and connect some wire but it's arcing electricity like crazy.

Comment: Might be The Cloverfield Paradox.

Comment: That would be my guess as well, @SDH. To be clear, the "apparently dead astronaut" in that film is the severed arm of an astronaut. If that sounds familiar, you have a winner :)

Comment: [Here on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2pG30-rpm0) is the arm from _The Cloverfield Paradox_ writing.  But there are more than three astronauts.

Comment: @John Parizeau - A new user with the name 'Highgate Hillbilly' has attempted to edit this question. If that's you, and you've lost access to the account you used to post this question, please merge your accounts by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). In doing so, you'll be recognised as the author of the question and regain the ability to edit it without approval from other users, post comments beneath it or other users' answers, and mark an answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

This might be [*Dark Star*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Star_(film)) (1974).  From that wikipedia article:

> Commanding officer Powell has died in one such event (electrocuted by his malfunctioning chair), but remains aboard in cryogenic suspension.
>
> …
>
> Doolittle revives Powell, who advises him to teach the bomb phenomenology.

I haven't seen it since it came out but have definite memories that it was hilarious when I did.

Still remember the conversation with the AI-impacted thermonuclear bomb ...

See the trailer at 2'10'' to see the start of the conversation with the dead commander.  The movie might not have him writing anything on a pad of paper though.

Comment: The movie does not have him writing anything on a pad of paper.

Comment: Ok, @DoscoJones, I wasn't sure.  But that doesn't take away anything from _Dark Star_, which everyone should see.  (Also, how many movies have dead astronauts speaking/writing/communicating to their still-alive crew?  2 so far - how many others are there?  Time for a new question ...)